# How can I stop activity being added to backstack

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle

how can I avoid adding an activity to a backstack.

This is how I start an activity

```
    startActivity(
        StripeConnectActivity.createIntent(
            context = baseContext,
            paymentSetupState = paymentSetupState,
            setupFlowType = SetupFlowType.STANDARD
        )
    )
```

Comment: Instead of not adding to the backstack you can finish it when moving on to the next activity. Please describe the scenario to get a better answer..

Answer (score 2):

Simply follow up your call to `startActivity()` with a `finish()` call to close the current activity so it won't be in the back stack.

```
startActivity(
    StripeConnectActivity.createIntent(
        context = baseContext,
        paymentSetupState = paymentSetupState,
        setupFlowType = SetupFlowType.STANDARD
    )
)
finish()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set flags to the intent

```
intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

or you can modify

```
    override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    }
```